# How to convert the word '' from utf-8 to gbk

Tags: c++, boost

Here is my code.
sz is word '䶮',sz2 is word '' They are both coding in utf-8.They are not same word on the binary level.
To convert them coding charset in GBK is what I want to see.
but I met a 'Conversion Failed' when the sz is transcoding.
I guess the problem is because their isn't have corresponding word in boost gbk codepage.if so how can I solve this problem. I'm not a English speaker.hope my decription won't let you confused.

```
char sz[] = { 0xE4,0xB6, 0xAE,0};
char sz2[] = { 0xEE, 0xA1,0xA3,0 };
fstream o("1.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

try {
    o << boost::locale::conv::from_utf(sz2, "gbk", boost::locale::conv::stop) << endl;
    o << boost::locale::conv::from_utf(sz, "gbk", boost::locale::conv::stop) << endl;
}
catch(boost::locale::conv::conversion_error e){
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}

o.close();
```

Comment: If GBK has no corresponging symbol, it's just not possible to properly convert it.

Comment: `boost::locale::conv::stop` says to stop on error, `boost::locale::conv::skip` would have skipped (ignored) ''.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my code. sz is word '䶮',sz2 is word '' They are both coding in utf-8.

The second one is simply unknown: (see also http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e863/index.htm)

> 
>
> ```
> Character:  U+E863
> Name: <Private Use>
> General Character Properties
> Block: Private Use Area
> Unicode category: Other, Private Use
> ```

Therefore, it can quite naturally not be converted.

> ***UPDATE***: GB18030 supports the entire Unicode space, and is a superset of GBK. You might be able to use that instead of GBK.

Just accept this and use

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9a73885737c9b7)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    auto CN = gen.generate("zh_CN.GBK");

    for (std::string const input : {
        std::string { static_cast<char>(0xE4), static_cast<char>(0xB6), static_cast<char>(0xAE), 0 },
        std::string { static_cast<char>(0xEE), static_cast<char>(0xA1), static_cast<char>(0xA3), 0 },
    })
    {
        std::ofstream o("1.dat", std::ios::binary);
        o.imbue(CN);

        try {
            o << boost::locale::conv::from_utf(input, "GBK", boost::locale::conv::skip) << "\n";
            std::cout << "Conversion ok!\n";
        }
        catch(boost::locale::conv::conversion_error e){
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Conversion ok!
Conversion ok!
```

Of course this loses information if input uses non-standard/unknown code points.

Comment: PS. I just learned that GB18030 supports the entire Unicode space, and is a superset of GBK. You might be interested to use that over GBK.